# Powershell - Can you use a custom object type contraint for function parameters?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a function defined as follows:

```
function Get-LatestProjects
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Company.Project.Entities.Project[]] $Projects
    )
    Begin {}
    Process
    {
        ...
    }
    End {}
}
```

I'm calling this function from C# and the parameter in the code is an array of that type, but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Projects'. Cannot convert the "Company.Project.Entities.Project[]" value of type "Company.Project.Entities.Project[]" to type "Company.Project.Entities.Project".

The C# code that makes the call:

```
var script = @". \\server01\Runspace.ps1; Get-LatestProjects $args";
var args = _pmRepository.GetAllProjects().ToArray(); // GetAllProjects returns List<Project>

using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runSpace.Open();
    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runSpace;
    ps.AddScript(script);
    ps.AddArgument(args);

    Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
    ...
}
```

Do I need to do any conversion of the objects before I pass them to the powershell function?  Or can I not add a type constraint in the powershell function for the $Projects parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like _pmRepository.GetAllProjects() return only one project. Can't you just declare $Projects without type and use $Projects.gettype to have a look to the type.

```
function Get-LatestProjects
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Projects
    )
    Begin {
       #Set-Content -path c:\temp\debug.txt -value $Projects.Gettype()
       $projects | get-member -force | out-file -filepath c:\temp\debug.txt
    }
    Process
    {
        for ($i=0 ; $i -le $projects.count ; $i++)
        {
           $projects[$i].State  | out-file  -filepath c:\temp\debug.txt -append
        }
    }
    End {}
}
```

----Edited------

You can avoid your array to be wraped into another array by writting.

```
var script = @". \\server01\Runspace.ps1; Get-LatestProjects $args[0]";
```

Comment: I Edit answer to continue debug

Comment: TypeName: Company.Project.Entities.Project[]

Name               MemberType    Definition                                     
----               ----------    ----------                                     
Count              AliasProperty Count = Length                                 
pstypenames        CodeProperty  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[...
psadapted          MemberSet     psadapted {Length, LongLength, Rank, SyncRoo...
psbase             MemberSet     psbase {Length, LongLength, Rank, SyncRoot, ...
psextended         MemberSet     psextended {Count} ...

Comment: I Edit answer to continue debug

Comment: I added $Projects.Count to the Begin block and it's showing 1.  I know for a fact that the array I'm passing in has 2082 items in it, I verified it.  When I run your updated code I get `Property 'State' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.`

Comment: So try to retreive the type of $projects[0] with Get-Member

Comment: I was able to get at all the Project's by looking at $Projects[0].  I'm not sure why it wrapped it inside another array.